# web user controls have made my default page so heavy

Tags: asp.net, ajax

my web site structure is like this :
    1- master page with stylesheet and scripts 
    2- aspx which render (number 3)
    3- web user control and scripts inside them

 in the number 3 I have some javascript that are call some ajax method they are about 20 lines code and I can not move them to js file in order to using <%= myAspControl.ClientID %> for some purpose
 my default.aspx is so heavily now I checked it by google chrome developer tools it is equal to 2.7MB for document only document not images or style sheet.
I have about ten controls but I think it is effect on viewstate and encoding them it creates all in default.aspx dynamicly and make it so heavy.

Comment: viewstate *is* probably why it's so heavy.  What is your question?

Comment: the question is what is the solution for decrease the size ?

Comment: in order to see if there is a way to reduce the size of the viewstate, there needs to be more information about the page, are you storing anything in the viewstate beyond control information?  How many user controls are you hosting in the page? (A lot of user controls, even if they are not rendered, will make the viewstate huge)

Comment: I have written a smartpager control and treeview both need viewstate

Comment: Does the pager control try to stash the entire DataSet or whatever datasource you are using into the viewstate or are you going back to someother medium to retrieve the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you read [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/803277/minimize-viewstate-with-treeview) SO-suggestions to minimize ViewState?

Answer (score 0):

That seems like poor ViewState use. I saw it in a project with some Telerik controls, which had a feature that stored the whole data source in the ViewState / which included more than was being displayed.

Keep the ViewState to what's absolutely necessary. Don't try any clever workaround, you should never store large amount of info in the view state.