# Huge ASP.NET Web Forms

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I looking for strategies others have taken for handling ASP.NET web forms with huge numbers of fields. For example, we have a single page that can have around 200 fields and 3 data entry grids in user controls, Now were looking to add even more.  It seems to me that at some point the viewstate, or something, is going to break down. So I'm interested to hear how others have handled this level of fields.

MORE INFO BASED ON GOOD FEEDBACK BELOW: I'm thinking maybe changing my main form to more of a dashboard, and when the user wants to enter/edit a data section they get redirected to a new page entirely. When they're done it redirects back. We already have user controls for the 3 grids (totally different types of data).  But User Controls I'm finding are nightmares as far as when they render, interactions with the "parent" etc.

Comment: 200 fields would be a nice experience for user !!!!! Part it into different wizards

Comment: Can you break the fields into logical groupings? This might be a good time for some persisted state and workflow-type functionality.

Comment: AJAX - http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-consume-aspnet-json-web-services/  But if you're going to rebuild the functionality like this or using any of the other currently given solutions why not simply migrate from WebForms to MVC (my recommendation).

Comment: Wow.  200+ fields?  And I was kvetching about 45 fields.  Do you have a problem with the page timing out for users while they struggle to fill in such a massive form?

Comment: I've had to deliver a giant form, such as that as my client demanded it and wouldn't entertain any alternative. They were used to an old Access data input screen, and wanted the same for the web. As I mention in my answer below, one customer's order screen has a grid with over 1500 controls.

Comment: @ChrisHardie Sounds like I'd use code generation there.

Comment: Ya we just have a form, broken into sections luckily, that has close to 200 fields, not all of which they fill out every time. We actually did hit the 1000 controls issue and had to add the setting mentioned below to webconfig.

Answer (score 4):

I have a form with over 1500 form fields, no issues as of yet. You should be fine unless your server is resource anemic or you have extraordinary loads.

You should however take note of this massive gotcha that took me unawares:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2661403

By default, 1000 form controls is the max you can submit to your page. And there is no error thrown, the page will only accept the first 1000 items, and ignore the rest. Pretty awesome discovery in a production environment...

Fortunately you can override that default with this in your web.config:

```
<appSettings>
 <add key="aspnet:MaxHttpCollectionKeys" value="10000" />
</appSettings>
```

I wouldn't recommend forms with that many controls, but it was at the insistence of the client :)

Comment: That is really interesting, I had no idea there was a limit!  Also, gross (for having to create a page with >1,500 fields).

Comment: The customer is always right.... maybe.... And I didn't create the form, but created a single record with 20 editable fields, which the user could dupe if desired.

Comment: We hit that awhile ago! (Lots of controls besides just the fields).

Answer (score 1):

> I looking for strategies others have taken for handling ASP.NET web
>   forms with huge numbers of fields.

I like to share "a trick" that I use on the rare case of a form with hundreds of fields. On post back I eliminate the fields that actually not change, or they have some default input. On post back I know the fields that I have eliminate and usually for the default action I do not need to do anything. Eg a not select check box, or an input field that have not change, etc....

That way, the actually post is significant smaller. For example on jQuery here is a simple code:

```
function cOnSubmit()
{
    jQuery(".MyInputCss").each(function(index, domElem) 
    {
        var me = jQuery(domElem);

        // just an example - if the default have selected of no action, I eliminate it.
        if(me.find("input[type='radio']:checked").val() == "-1")
        {
            // removing the name is not take part on the post back
            me.find("input").removeAttr("name");
        }
    });

    return true;
}
```

and on the form I call this function as:

```
<form .... onsubmit="return cOnSubmit();">
```

Answer (score 1):

> It seems to me that at some point the viewstate, or something, is
>   going to break down.

**1)** If you have a lot of control, you will end up with **Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object**.

It can easily be fixed by using [MaxHttpCollectionKeys](http://timjames.me/asp-net-maxhttpcollectionkeys-in-app-config) like Chris Hardie's suggested.

*Note: a label server control is also counted as one control in addition to textbox server control.*

**2)** The another problem I can think of will be **large ViewState**.

In order to solve this, you can either store ViewState in [StateServer or SQL Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178586.ASPX).

### Update 12/20/2013:

Sorry, I forget to mention how to save ViewState to Session.

Since you already store SessionState is SQL Server, all you need is to inherit the aspx pages from this BasePage.

```
public class BasePage : Page
{
  protected PageStatePersister _persister;

  protected override PageStatePersister PageStatePersister
  {
    get { return _persister ?? (_persister=new SessionPageStatePersister(this));}
  }
}
```

Comment: Viewstate can be stored in SQL Server? I missed that in your link. I know Session state can and we do do that.

Comment: My bad. I updated my answer. Similar answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/484656/296861). *That small trick could save a lot of bandwidth especially a lot of controls like yours.*

Comment: Well how about that.  +1 to you, I didn't know it was that easy.