# Invalid Viewstate or Truncated Viewstate by Firewall or Proxy

Tags: c#, asp.net, proxy, firewall, viewstate

We have been getting a lot of errors like this in our prod environment which are not reproducible on DEV for our asp.net webforms application:

> The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64character, 
>       more than two padding characters, or a non-white space character among the padding 
>       characters.
>
> at System.Convert.FromBase64String(String s)
>   at System.Web.UI.ObjectStateFormatter.Deserialize(String inputString)
>   at System.Web.UI.ObjectStateFormatter.System.Web.UI.IStateFormatter.Deserialize(String serializedState)
>   at System.Web.UI.Util.DeserializeWithAssert(IStateFormatter formatter, String serializedState)
>   at System.Web.UI.HiddenFieldPageStatePersister.Load()
>   Error   WTAS-ADM01  global_asax Application_Error   App_global.asax
>
> An un-handled application error has occured: Invalid viewstate.

I have done a quick research on such errors and come to know that the most probable reason behind them is that the Viewstate on the page is being truncated by some firewall or proxy. But I am not sure if these things actually are the reason.

Can anyone please guide me on how to reproduce this on my DEV environment. So, that atleast I can become double sure that these are really the culprits.

Answer (score 0):

It's going to be difficult to reproduce how your firewall/proxy handles your requests.

The simpler way would be [to persist your viewstate on the server-side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/386131/keeping-viewstate-in-sessionpagestatepersister) to test it out; if it works on your dev box and in prod, you know it's really about those things truncating your Viewstate.